# SQLite results not showing data

Tags: sqlite

The query returns results, but the data returned is just the column names instead of the data in the rows.

```
select
    "unique id",
    "med class",
    "med date",
    "med exp date"
from
    pilot_cert
where
    "unique id" = "A3875861";
```

returns:

```
unique id   med class   med date    med exp date
A3875861    med class   med date    med exp date
```

There is data on this row, but it will not show in the above query (copied and pasted from results window):

```
A3875861    HARRISON    FORD    3100 DONALD DOUGLAS LOOP N  STE 204 SANTA MONICA    CA  90405-3084  USA WP  2   52019   52020
```

sorry for all the edits :)

Answer (score 0):

From [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: **"key"** or **"glob"**) is used in a context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string literal instead of an identifier.

The results indicate there is a column name (identifier) of "unique id"; the other 3 are understood to be string literals. The query needs to use the correct column names from the pilot_cert table.